# Linking two calendars using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, calendar

I have a question.
I have 2 calendars on an aspx.
I want to keep them synchronized.
What I want is that when I switch on Calendar1 to a month, Calendar2 should go to the same month.

WHen I open my page they are both on the current month.
When I jump to May on Calendar1 I want Calendar2 to display May as well.

Comment: You want this on date selection? or like scrolling past the calender aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the selection changed event and visible month event...

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  
       SelectionMode="DayWeekMonth" 
       ShowGridLines="True"             
       OnSelectionChanged="Selection_Change"
       OnVisibleMonthChanged="MonthChange"></asp:Calendar>
```

And in the code behind

```
Sub Selection_Change(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    'Calendar2.SelectedDates = Calendar1.SelectedDates
     For Each day In Calendar1.SelectedDates
         Calendar2.SelectedDates.Add(day)
     Next
End Sub

Sub MonthChange(sender As Object, e As MonthChangedEventArgs) 
    Calendar2.VisibleDate = e.NewDate
End Sub
```